# Difference between ODAS and Wireless APs

Tags: wireless

ODAS (Outdoor Distributed Antenna System) and Wireless APs - From what I know ODAS connects to Cellular towers while APs go through the Wireless Technology? Please add some more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***A DAS*** is a system of managed hubs and remote antennas that distribute a wireless signal to a series of connected indoor or ***outdoor*** multi-band, multi-technology radio heads as shown:

[image]

At the head-end of the DAS, service providers typically locate base stations to provide the cellular signal. A main hub takes that signal, digitizes it, and distributes it to other hubs and radio heads via a high-bandwidth fiber optic network. At the antenna, the radio converts the signals from digital to RF and RF to digital. You can find more about DAS in this link [DAS tech](http://electronicdesign.com/communications/understanding-distributed-antenna-systems-dass)

***The answer to your question:***

1. This style of wireless implementation is suitable for Wi-Fi, but
   only 5% of commercial Wi-Fi implementations use a distributed antenna system. It is more common for mobile network indoor and outdoor implementations. On the other side, APs are used for Wi-Fi in most implementation scenarios (e.g. mesh connections).
2. DAS acts as one big controller with multiple antennas (one huge AP),
   but AP Wi-Fi implementations distribute and control the APs
   themselves.